# Placing an entire Bootstrap 3 <div> into a Javascript array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, twitter-bootstrap

so I'm new to web development. I'm trying to get a div with images and containers into an array, allowing me to hide the entire div with a (display: none) and then have another div in the second array slot show with (display: block). I'm not sure how too do this but this is my attempt so far.

HTML:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="col-xs-1 col-xs-push-1 rightLeftChevrons">
    <a href="#" class="btn-xxl btn-color btn-block" id="leftControl" onclick=""><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left center-block" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-10">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row" id="imagesSlide">
            <div id="imagesTabsOne">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <div class="well well-lg" id="imageWell">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-4">
                                <img class="img-responsive img-center img-rounded" src="http://placehold.it/256x256&text=Image" alt="imagesImage">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-4">
                                <img class="img-responsive img-center img-rounded" src="http://placehold.it/256x256&text=Image" alt="imagesImage">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-4">
                                <img class="img-responsive img-center img-rounded" src="http://placehold.it/256x256&text=Image" alt="imagesImage">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-4">
                                <img class="img-responsive img-center img-rounded" src="http://placehold.it/256x256&text=Image" alt="imagesImage">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-4">
                                <img class="img-responsive img-center img-rounded" src="http://placehold.it/256x256&text=Image" alt="imagesImage">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-4">
                                <img class="img-responsive img-center img-rounded" src="http://placehold.it/256x256&text=Image" alt="imagesImage">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-4">
                                <img class="img-responsive img-center img-rounded" src="http://placehold.it/256x256&text=Image" alt="imagesImage">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-4">
                                <img class="img-responsive img-center img-rounded" src="http://placehold.it/256x256&text=Image" alt="imagesImage">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-4">
                                <img class="img-responsive img-center img-rounded" src="http://placehold.it/256x256&text=Image" alt="imagesImage">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="imagesTabsTwo">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <div class="well well-lg" id="imageWell">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-4">
                                <img class="img-responsive img-center img-rounded" src="http://placehold.it/256x256&text=Image2" alt="imagesImage">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-4">
                                <img class="img-responsive img-center img-rounded" src="http://placehold.it/256x256&text=Image2" alt="imagesImage">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-4">
                                <img class="img-responsive img-center img-rounded" src="http://placehold.it/256x256&text=Image2" alt="imagesImage">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-4">
                                <img class="img-responsive img-center img-rounded" src="http://placehold.it/256x256&text=Image2" alt="imagesImage">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-4">
                                <img class="img-responsive img-center img-rounded" src="http://placehold.it/256x256&text=Image2" alt="imagesImage">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-4">
                                <img class="img-responsive img-center img-rounded" src="http://placehold.it/256x256&text=Image2" alt="imagesImage">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-4">
                                <img class="img-responsive img-center img-rounded" src="http://placehold.it/256x256&text=Image" alt="imagesImage">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-4">
                                <img class="img-responsive img-center img-rounded" src="http://placehold.it/256x256&text=Image" alt="imagesImage">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-4">
                                <img class="img-responsive img-center img-rounded" src="http://placehold.it/256x256&text=Image" alt="imagesImage">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-1 col-xs-pull-1 rightLeftChevrons" id="rightControl">
    <button class="btn-xxl btn-color btn-block" onclick="imagesTabSlide()"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right center-block" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
var IS_i = 0;
var elem_IS = document.getElementById('imagesSlide');
var pageOne = document.getElementById('imagesTabsOne');
var pageTwo = document.getElementById('imagesTabsTwo');
var imagesTabsArray = [pageOne, pageTwo];

function imagesTabNext(){

    IS_i++;
    elem_IS.style.display = "none";
    if (IS_i > (imagesTabsArray.length -1)){
        IS_i = 0;
    }
    setTimeout('imagesTabSlide()',1000);
}

function imagesTabSlide(){

    elem_IS.innerHTML = imagesTabsArray[IS_i];
    elem_IS.style.display = "block";
    setTimeout('imagesTabNext()',2000);

}
```

Currently it's set to activate on the button press just for testing purposes.

It all almost works too, but I get [object HTMLDivElement] instead of my div.

Basically I want to make a slide show with the div blocks I created.

Answer (score 0):

`innerHTML` is a string, and anything you try to assign to it will be converted to string, that's why you get "[object HTMLDivElement]".

Instead, you can insert your element into the tree by using `appendChild`:

```
    elem_IS.appendChild( imagesTabsArray[IS_i] );
```

But then, you will probably want to remove the other element from there, won't you? To achieve that, you can do:

```
    elem_IS.removeChild( elem_IS.firstChild );
```

Also, don't pass a string as first argument to `setTimeout`: it's a performance penalty, and also requires your functions to be global. Pass the function instead:

```
    setTimeout( imagesTabNext, 2000 );
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `innerHTML`. That will retrieve the div blocks from the object you created.

```
elem_IS.innerHTML = imagesTabsArray[IS_i.innerHTML];
```